# GridView MultiChoiceModeListener not showing in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview

**Background**

I have an `Activity` which contains a `Fragment`. The `Fragment` contains a `GridView` which displays a number of items. The items implements the checkable interface which changes background color depending on their state, and is working as intended.

Now I'd like to implement a `MultiChoiceModeListener` for my `GridViewItem`s.

The problem is that I've set a `MultiChoiceModeListener` on the `GridView` but it does not show up when I click on my items in the `GridView`.

**Code**

Activity.java:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {       
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        setUpComponents();
    }

    private void setUpComponents(){
        //Setting up buttons etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new ChoosePhotosFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment.java:

```
public class ChoosePhotosFragment extends Fragment implements MediaStoreProvider.OnQueryResultListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;
    private ArrayList<GridViewObject> objects;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_photos, container, false);
        objects = new ArrayList<>();
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gvChoosePhotos);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), objects);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        getData();

        return v;
    }

    public void getData() {
        //Fetching and setting up the adapter with data.
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println(gridView.isItemChecked(position));
    }

    public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements
            GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Select Items");
            mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
            System.out.println("onCreateActionMode");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            System.out.println("onActionItemClicked");
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                              long id, boolean checked) {
            System.out.println("onItemCheckedStateChanged");
            int selectCount = gridView.getCheckedItemCount();
            switch (selectCount) {
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GridViewItem.xml:

```
<com.marcusjacobsson.vault.widgets.CheckableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_item_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</com.marcusjacobsson.vault.widgets.CheckableLayout>
```

CheckableLayout.java:

```
public class CheckableLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

    public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CheckableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        if (b != mChecked) {
            mChecked = b;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }
}
```

The background selector of my CheckableLayout (The background changes color depending on the state of the CheckableLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" >
        <!-- This applies when the item is checked. -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <solid android:color="#000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <!-- This applies when the item is not checked. -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Finally, the GridView which is housed in the ChoosePhotosFragment layout:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvChoosePhotos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
```

**Problem statement and question**

As stated above, when I check/click an item in my `GridView` I expect the `MultiChoiceMode` to overlap the `ActionBar`. This is currently not the case. The `MultiChoiceMode` is not invoked at all (no `System.out` messages gets printed to the log and no action mode is visually present).

I've tried the following without success:

- Setting the `ImageView` and `TextView` in the GridViewItem.xml to
  `clickable="false"` and `checkable="false"`.
- Changing `GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` to
  `GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` (This did not only not work,
  but also stopped the `GridView` items from changing background as if
  they no longer changed state)

I can not figure out what's wrong, so my question is simply; what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for an answer to this question, but I've implemented a temporary workaround using [the contextual action mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB). The difference from `MultiChoiceListener` would be that I handle checking/unchecking of items with `GridView.OnItemClickListener` instead of the `onItemCheckedStateChanged` method provided by the `MultiChoiceListener`.